# Java - Inject java agent in to running jvm

Tags: java, jvm, classloader, javaagents

Basically, I am trying to write something that lists every class loaded by the JVM. What I wrote works, but it only works for the jvm it is running on.
I crafted a java agent to dynamically inject into another JVM, but then realized I don't actually know how to inject it.
How do I actually send this agent into another JVM?
Is it possible?

Comment: You can use [jvm-attach](https://github.com/mageddo-projects/jvm-attach), no JDK needed

Answer (score 11):

Agents can be injected with [HotSpot Attach API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jdk/api/attach/spec/).
Run the following snippet with `$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar` on the class path.

```
    VirtualMachine vm = VirtualMachine.attach(PID);
    try {
        vm.loadAgent(agentJar);
    } finally {
        vm.detach();
    }
```

Alternatively you may do this with my command-line [jattach](https://github.com/apangin/jattach) utility:

```
$ jattach PID load instrument false /path/to/agent.jar
```

Note that in order to support dynamic attach, your Java agent should have `agentmain` method and `Agent-Class` property in `MANIFEST.MF`.

Comment: I have a small problem with the agents. I am assuming that it's the most standard practice to pack your instrumentation agent separately from your target JVM. When my `agentmain()` is called I tried to find a JVM class by calling `Class.forName("pkg.name")` but it is always returning `NoClassDefFoundError`. I have posted the question here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46523055/using-class-forname-in-java-instrumentation-agent?noredirect=1#comment80003396_46523055)[here]. I am slightly confused why the agent, even when attached to the VM, cannot refer to its classes.

Comment: Alternativelly you can use [jvm-attach](https://github.com/mageddo-projects/jvm-attach) which is a wrapper for jattach to make instrumentation programatically, no tools.jar or JDK needed

Answer (score 11):

Dynamic agents need to declare an `agentmain(String, Instrumentation)` method which is executed upon attachment within the target VM. You can use the *tools.jar* dependency which is (until Java 9) only included in a JDK but not a JRE. You can however bundle your agent program with a JDK and attach to JVMs from there.

The biggest pitfall is that the API differs for different VMs; you can however use a library like [*byte-buddy-agent*](https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy/tree/master/byte-buddy-agent) which contains different implementations for different VMs. An attachment can be done using:

```
ByteBuddyAgent.attach("my.jar", "my-pid");
```

This attaches the agent contained in *my.jar* onto the Java process with id `my-id`.

Comment: Yes. The OS process id.

Comment: I attempted to do this, and under testing it appears my agentmain method is never being called.

Comment: On further inspection, the agentmain method is only being called if I attach to the JVM it is running on.

Comment: It is called by the target vm.

Comment: Basically what I am trying to do is get an instance of the Instrumentation. If the target vm calls agentmain, does that make getting an instance of a different JVM's instrumentation impossible?

Comment: That is impossible!  You could however proxy the interface and run some form of receiver on the other VM that executes the commands.

Comment: Did you use a JDK?

Comment: @RafaelWinterhalter            does this handle webapp classloading delegation? When you go inside the agent, classloading is not the same as your webapplication classloading....So you have a delegation mechanism working in there?

Comment: @RafaelWinterhalter How can I create 'File' of my agent jar?

Comment: You have to create a jar, just like for any Java program.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I understand from [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38948847/java-inject-java-agent-in-to-running-jvm/38950616#comment65279421_38950874), you are interested in something that can inspect remote JVM from within another Java process. If it is the case, then you need a [Serviceability Agent](http://openjdk.java.net/groups/hotspot/docs/Serviceability.html#bsa) rather than Java Agent.

[Serviceability Agent API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/serviceabilityagent/index.html) allows you to attach to another JVM process, to read its memory, to reconstruct VM structures and to inspect remote objects in reflection-like manner.

Here is a sample tool to list all classes loaded by a remote JVM:

```
import sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.VM;
import sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool;

public class ListRemoteClasses extends Tool {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ListRemoteClasses().execute(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        VM.getVM().getSystemDictionary().classesDo(klass -> {
            String className = klass.getName().asString().replace('/', '.');
            System.out.println(className);
        });
    }
}
```

How to run it:

```
java -cp $JAVA_HOME/lib/sa-jdi.jar:. ListRemoteClasses PID
```

Answer (score -1):

It's hard to provide assistance without looking at the content that you've written but this is just to notify that there is a class named as Instrumentation interface (`public interface Instrumentation`) from `java.lang.instrument` package that provides services needed to instrument Java programming language code.

One such method provided by this class is `getInitiatedClasses` which returns an array containing all the classes that are loaded.

Look at the documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html#getInitiatedClasses(java.lang.ClassLoader))

> **getInitiatedClasses**
>
> *Class[] getInitiatedClasses(ClassLoader loader)*
>   Returns an array of all classes for which loader is an initiating loader. If the
>   supplied loader is null, classes initiated by the bootstrap class
>   loader are returned.
>
> ***Parameters:***   loader - the loader whose initiated class list will be returned
>   ***Returns:***   an array containing all the classes for which loader is an initiating loader, zero-length if there are none

Comment: I am aware of this. The problem is that the jar is already running and I need to get a javaagent to connect with it.